# Convert multithreading to multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-2.6, python-multiprocessing

How to i convert this thing from multithreading to multiprocessing? With the multithreading it actually runs slower while not much CPU is used. So I hope that multiprocessing might help.

```
  def multiprocess(sentences):

     responselist = []

     #called by each thread
     def processfunction(asentence,i):
         pro_sentence = processthesentence(asentence[0],asentence[1],asentence[2],asentence[3],asentence[4],asentence[5],asentence[6],asentence[7],asentence[8])
         mytyple = asentence,pro_sentence
         responselist.append(mytyple)

     # ----- function end --------- #

     #start threading1
     threadlist = []
     for i in range (2):
         asentence = sentences[i]
         t = Thread(target=processfunction, args=(asentence,i,))
         threadlist.append(t)
         t.start()

     for thr in threadlist:
         thr.join()

     return responselist
```

I tried this (replacing one word - Thread with Process but this doesn't work):

```
  from multiprocessing import Process 

  def processthesentence(asentence):
      return asentence + " done"

  def multiprocess(sentences):

     responselist = []

     #called by each thread
     def processfunction(asentence,i):
         pro_sentence = processthesentence(asentence)
         mytyple = asentence,pro_sentence
         responselist.append(mytyple)

     # ----- function end --------- #

     #start threading1
     threadlist = []
     for i in range (2):
         asentence = sentences[i]
         t = Process(target=processfunction, args=(asentence,i,))
         threadlist.append(t)
         t.start()

     for thr in threadlist:
         thr.join()

     return responselist


  sentences = []
  sentences.append("I like apples.")
  sentences.append("Green apples are bad.")
  multiprocess(sentences)
```

Tried with greenevent but got some errors:

```
import greenlet
import gevent

def dotheprocess(sentences):

    responselist = []

    #called by each thread
    def task(asentence):
        thesentence = processsentence(asentence[0],asentence[1],asentence[2],asentence[3],asentence[4],asentence[5],asentence[6],asentence[7],asentence[8])

        mytyple = asentence,thesentence
        responselist.append(mytyple)

    # ----- function end --------- #

    def asynchronous():
        threads = [gevent.spawn(task, asentence) for asentence in sentences]
        gevent.joinall(threads)   

    asynchronous()

    return responselist
```

Comment: I tried to replace one word - Thread with Process, but this doesn't work because you cannot add process in an array I guess. I added the code in the question.

Comment: Looks like you just added an additional `import`. Why would it change anything ?

Comment: @alfasin - Mistake I replaces Thread with Process as well. But that leads to errors.

Comment: 1. I don't see how you're running it. 2. "but this doesn't work" is too vague - what exactly doesn't work, what's the expected output and what is the actual one. Do you get an error? if so, post the stacktrace...

Comment: where did you use the variable `i` in your function `processfunction()`

Comment: I do not use  variable "i"  but I put it there just in case I need it letter.

Comment: *I do not use variable "i" but I put it there just in case I need it later.* Don't do that. Write code for now. You should try harder to use multi processing. Don't expect to do find/replace thread to process and expect it to work. Do some research and apply yourself.

Comment: I didn't expect but since I have the code already, which is almost complete somebody who knows more about it should be able to complete it in 2 minutes.

Comment: @alfasin : I added the complete example of the code so you can try it.

Comment: So you can't be bothered to make any effort and expect us to do it?

Comment: I spent last 8 hours trying to various ways for multithreading  in php and python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked the best for me - it is around 50% faster that without use of it:

```
def processthesentence(asentence):
     return asentence

import multiprocessing as mympro 
if __name__=="__main__":
    sentences = ['I like something','Great cool']
    numberofprocesses = 3
    thepool = mympro.Pool(processes=numberofprocesses)
    results = [thepool.apply_async(processthesentence, args=(asent,)) for asent in sentences]
    output = [item.get() for item in results]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) to spawn multiple greenlets that will allow you to use others CPU. Here is an example according to yours. See that a Queue is used to be able to work ok across context switch of gevent

```
import greenlet
import gevent
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

def dotheprocess(sentences):
    queue = gevent.queue.Queue()
    #called by each thread

    def task(asentence):
        thesentence = processsentence(asentence[0],asentence[1],asentence[2],asentence[3],asentence[4],asentence[5],asentence[6],asentence[7],asentence[8])
        queue.put((asentence,thesentence))

    threads = [gevent.spawn(task, asentence) for asentence in sentences]
    gevent.joinall(threads)   

    return queue
#call the dotheprocess function with your sentences
```

Comment: I wrote the code but I got an eror - import greenlet
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Comment: Sorry. Only available for linux. Dll are windows only

Comment: You should specify better what is your target os system

Comment: I can install it on linux as well, and it helps, please see the code above and see if it is ok.

Comment: Why did you downvote the answer? It's a valid one for your question. That actions will not help you to get help

Comment: I didn't downvote it, I upvote it .. somebody else did it.

Comment: See an example of your gevent code modified in my previous answer. Note the mokey patch and the queue use

Comment: It cannot be used on windows I guess?

Comment: You need to find the gevent and greenlet installer packages for Window. I read that newest versions give support using libev

Comment: I did install it through pip but still doesnt work. Will try on linux.

Answer (score 1):

Threading doesn't make a function faster unless you have some wait functions(I/O implementations) in your thread. Multiprocessing will help in theory, but simple functions wouldn't benefit much from it because of the overhead so use it carefully. Use `Manager` for shared variable.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager, freeze_support

class multiProcess():
    def __init__(self, sentences):
        self.responseList = Manager().list()
        self.processList = []
        self.sentences = sentences

    def processSentence(self,a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8):
        reversedValue = a8+a7+a6+a5+a4+a3+a2+a1+a0
        return reversedValue

    #called by each process
    def processFunction(self,asentence):
        pro_sentence = self.processSentence(asentence[0],asentence[1],asentence[2],asentence[3],asentence[4],asentence[5],asentence[6],asentence[7],asentence[8])
        mytuple = (asentence,pro_sentence)
        self.responseList.append(mytuple)
        return

    def run(self):
        for i in range(2):
            asentence = self.sentences[i]
            p = Process(target=self.processFunction, args=(asentence,))
            self.processList.append(p)
            p.start()

        for pro in self.processList:
            pro.join()

        return self.responseList


if __name__=="__main__":
    freeze_support()
    sentences = ['interesting','wonderful']
    output = multiProcess(sentences).run()
    print(output)
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I run it but I am getting a lot of errors. Maybe because I use python 2.7.3?

Comment: i tested it with `python2.7.9` only, but yea basically use `Manager` and you should be fine

Comment: What is the meaning of if __name__=="__main__": ? Must I use it and can I use it in a function? I know this is basic but I never used it so far after a lot of scripts that I wrote.

Comment: you should google it yourself, and no here you don't have to use it, it's for dumping tests in

Comment: Cool. So you do not get any error here? Do you run on linux maybe? I am on windows?

Comment: My bad, you need `__name__=="__main__"` on windows, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows

Comment: Try it again, added `freeze_support`, maybe that's the problem

Comment: Thanks, I am still getting errors probably problem with python install - WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified